# C# Struct or something similar

Tags: c#, database, struct, long-integer, guid

I have been wondering if I could build a struct that could be both Guid and long.

[`EntityWorker.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityWorker.Core/) has a property called `Id` of type `System.long`.

I've been wondering if I could make it so the user choose between Guid and Long with help of a struct.

What do you think, is this possible?

This is what I have right now which I really don't like

```
public event Events.IdChanged OnIdChanged;

private long _id;

/// <summary>
/// This Key is generated on Item Insert
/// </summary>
public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }

[PrimaryKey]
public virtual long Id
{
    get => _id;
    set
    {
        if (value != _id)
        {
            _id = value;
            OnIdChanged?.Invoke(_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think I understand what exactly you are asking here. What do you mean choose between Guid and long? If your entity requires a long, then where does the Guid come into play?

Comment: No. You cannot create a struct that could be both. Guid and long are different types. You only could create a struct with to properties, one of type Guid and one of type long. But I also do not see the reason. What is the type of primary key of the entity? This will also be the primary key in the database.

Comment: This is what struct and operator is used for. you build a struct that take both long and guid. and i have GlobalConfigration that the user could set  PrimaryID type in Application_Start Method. so intead of long we could have somthing like ObjectId which could be both types. but i really dont know how exactly this work. is this a good idee or not ?

Comment: Why don't you just make a class that holds both a guid and a long. ? Or create a base class "Key" which  "LongKey" and "GuidKey" classes that inherit from the base class.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
usingSystem.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ExplicitStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid AGuid;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public long ALong;
}
```

However, note the following code which uses it:

```
    ExplicitStruct es = new ExplicitStruct();
    es.AGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    Console.WriteLine("AGuid: {0}", es.AGuid.ToString());
    es.ALong = 256;
    Console.WriteLine("AGuid: {0} ALong {1}", es.AGuid.ToString(), es.ALong.ToString());
```

The output is:

[image]

Set the Guid and display it: as expected.
Rhen set the long and display them both: oops! The Guid has changed! Which of course is expected; also after setting the Guid, the long would not be zero.

Comment: Thx your answer was good but i decided to let the user create the property so i dont need this any longer.